# How to fix a connection by web control panel Froxlor to MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, database, connection, root

I installed Apache2 and MySQL client/server and PHP8.1.2 manually. Ubuntu 22.04 successfully connected to the database from the terminal, changed the root password, exit.

Next, I tried to install the web control panel.

I first downloaded Froxlor from git https://github.com/Froxlor/Froxlor
to the /var/www/froxlor
master branch folder. Then I installed all the dependencies from the list, but this was not enough. The PHP application code gave out unsatisfied dependencies.

Here https://deb.froxlor.org/debian/pool/main/f/froxlor/ found the DEB package and installed it in the same folder through the terminal, satisfying all the dependencies with this - the code worked.

Then I started the installation. through the browser. By going to /index.php I am offered no options to go to ./install/, where I fill in all the relevant fields (maybe not correctly?) in the second window of the page and after clicking "submit" I get an error:

```
Checking MySQL-root access...   SQLSTATE[HY000] [1698] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
There seems to be a problem with the database-connection. Cannot continue. Please go back and check your credentials.
```

such an error crashes in the terminal if you connect to the database without "sudo", here I was confused. I have researched /install/lib/class.FroxlorInstall.php on the subject of at least some zatseki what should I do and still tried to add "sudo" in the file /tests/bootstrap.php in line 50
exec("sudo mysql -u root -p" . $rpwd . " froxlor010 " . dirname(**DIR**) . "/install/froxlor.sql");

but it didn't lead to anything. Maybe there is some similar experience, please tell me.  Thx

P.S. I also tried to install via froxlor.phar, but my installation hung up at the moment of connecting to the database, perhaps the script was waiting for the password to be entered, but this was not reflected.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I solve it by my self.

It need to create file ../froxlor/lib/userdata.inc.php by this example:

```
<?php
// automatically generated userdata.inc.php for Froxlor
$sql['host']='localhost';
$sql['user']='froxlor012';
$sql['password']='PASS';
$sql['db']='froxlor';
$sql['ssl']['caFile']='';
$sql['ssl']['verifyServerCertificate']='0';
$sql_root[0]['caption']='Default';
$sql_root[0]['host']='localhost';
$sql_root[0]['user']='frox';
$sql_root[0]['password']='PASS';
$sql_root[0]['ssl']['caFile']='';
$sql_root[0]['ssl']['verifyServerCertificate']='0';
// enable debugging to browser in case of SQL errors
$sql['debug'] = false;
?>
```

also you need to create 'froxlor','froxlor012' and 'frox' users (step forward: dont foget to change the PASS's, it may not be empty, and to GRANT users to 'froxlor' database) and empty 'froxlor' database ( step forward: if you have no back up of DB you can take back up of this example https://www.dropbox.com/s/6guus4uxc9v2agf/froxlorbackup.sql?dl=0 ) in MySQL, then run in terminal:

```
sudo php /var/www/froxlor/install/scripts/config-services.php --froxlor-dir=/var/www/froxlor/ --create 

sudo mysql -h localhost -u 'root' froxlor < /home/administrator/froxlorbackup.sql
```

so we have manualy install froxlor without any mistakes of installer. You will find user name froxlor with PASS in DB backup.